# How to train Matlab on a range of IP addresses?

Tags: data-mining, decision-trees, matlab, preprocessing

I'd like to train a Decision Tree using  the Classification Learner App. I have a range of IP addresses, and a country that the IP address range belongs to.

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","AU"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","CN"
"1.4.0.0","1.4.0.255","AU"
```

I've been thinking the whole day, but I can't figure out how to represent the range in the Matlab. The first step should be to convert the IP address to an integer. Yes, that's easy, but I'll have a range of numbers again. I don't want to replace the range with 255 lines (in the first case) or with even more lines. How to tell Matlab to handle the address range in an appropriate way?

The goal of this project is to train a tree using the test data (IP address range), then use the tree to determine the coutry of the given (single) IP address, not a range.
Thanks.

Comment: You might not find someone who uses that app here; better ask on the [MATLAB Answers forum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more principled way to go about this but I don't know how IP assignment works. That said,

All your information content appears to be in the second 2 numbers. The last 0-255 might be assumed and the leading 1 can be dropped. You might have something more complicated but as you lay it out, you can leave them as strings and assign to 3 groups: 
'0.0', 
'0.1 or '0.3'
'4.0'

You may not need to spell out all possible IPs. Define your problem space first.